# Please put me on the right track with Drag Drop on IOS

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios5, touchesmoved

I am creating a bit of a video mash up app (like imovie) and the first function I am tackling is the ability to drag a thumbnail from a video library and drop it on a time line.  I was able to add the drag code to the video thumbnail class so when you touch it, it creates a drag proxy view which moves around when you move your finger.  Next I want to be able to drop it on the time line.

My Timeline is also a uiview and I am unsure of how it can receive notification that the thumbnail is being dragged over it!  It will need the position of the thumbnail so that it can show it on the timeline and the duration of the clip and such (information that I have attached to my video thumbnail object)

How would you approach this issue?  The App is for ipad and is on ios 5.

Thanks for any pointers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will most likely want to subclass the UIView.  You can look at this post:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/4130641/1535038

Mainly you will want to see if the My Timeline view is being touched, and then see if you are in the middle of a drag or not.

Comment: So as part of the TouchesMoved event on the thumbnail view, I would check to see if the Timeline UIView is being touched?  I tried adding the touches event handlers to the timeline, but they only get called when the touches originate on the timeline, not on the thumbnails which are above it.

Comment: You would want to compare the bounds of the first touch to see if it is overlapping. Try: CGRectContainsPoint(myTimelinerect, touchPoint)