# UIButton like behavior on custom subclass of UIView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uibutton

I have subclass of UIView

```
@interface TBL_CardView : UIView
```

It it internally have UIImageView for card image.

I need to handle touching of card in following way:

1. When I touch (and still hold) TBL_CardView I need to set orange borderColor.
2. If I am stil on top of TBL_CardView I need to set red borderColor.
3. If I am not on top of TBL_CardView, I have moved my finger, because I want to cancel touch, then borderColor is removed.

I know how to handle setting of borderColor:

```
self.layer.borderColor = [UIColor redColor].CGColor;
self.layer.borderWidth = 3.0f;
```

But I do not know what is the easiest way to implement thin button like behavior ?
Should I make it just as button, or use UIResponder or something else ?
What are pros and cons for each case ?

Comment: by "button like behavior" are you referring to target-action?

Comment: @David I basically need all 3 points from question. I do not know what is meant by `target-action`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    NSLog(@"%s", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__);

    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint touchLocation = [touch locationInView: self];
    BOOL isInside = [self pointInside: touchLocation withEvent: event];
    if (isInside)
    {
        //if logic
        NSLog(@"INSIDE");
    }
    else
    {
        //else logic
        NSLog(@"OUTSIDE");
    }
}
```

You could check out this post for information on how to implement button-like behaviour and respond to touches on a `UIView` or a subclass.

[Touch Event on UIView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4130496/touch-event-on-uiview)

What I usually do myself, however, is put a transparent (clear color and no title, not `alpha = 0.0`) `UIButton` on top of my `UIView` matching it s size and responding to the events I need instead. Check if it fits your needs.

Comment: Why do you make "UIButton on top of my UIView" is it not easier just to subclass UIButton ?